# Server calls failing randomly in when opening app from notification

Tags: swift, push-notification, urlsession

When the user taps a push notification, I am trying to navigate them to a specific section of the app which includes a server call with URLSession. However, the call randomly fails without retrying. Interestingly it never occurs on the simulator, only on the phone itself.

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, NSUnderlyingError=0x282b73ed0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <EF128892-04ED-45BD-9EF4-DEBA069B22BD>.<18>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <EF128892-04ED-45BD-9EF4-DEBA069B22BD>.<18>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=<server api url>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=<server api url>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

The error claims the network connection was lost, but that's not the case as other server calls are always working in the same session.

The code, in `AppDelegate`:

```
private lazy var dataSession:URLSession = {
    var config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    config.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    config.urlCache = nil
    config.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 8
    config.httpShouldSetCookies = false

    return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
}()

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
    guard response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier else {
        completionHandler()
        return 
    }
    
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: <url>)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    urlRequest.httpShouldHandleCookies = false
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.addValue(<authorizationHeader>, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    self.dataSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
        // Navigate to screen
    }
        
    completionHandler()
}
```

I've tried calling the `completionHandler` in the data task completion block but that didn't change anything.

How can I ensure the call will go through as it normally does in this method?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force this error to disappear, especially as it can happen for many legitimate reasons. As [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1941/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017602) says:

> ...as an app developer it’s reasonable to expect a small number of NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost errors caused by problems with the underlying network. However, if you’re seeing a large number of these errors, and especially if they are raised in environments with good network connectivity, there might be a problem with NSURLSession talking to your server. You can investigate that by looking at the on-the-wire traffic to see whether there’s an obvious underlying cause for these errors, for example, your server actually closing connections unexpectedly.

So what you can do is

- Identify more precisely if the error is something you can fix on your app side, or is it a problem with the server (which also is quite possible).
- And if the problem is on your side, or is due to unreliable networking (which for mobile apps should be something normal to handle too), decide how to improve your app to make such error a "no issue". For example you can retry a call, and/or you may want to show a user some sort of spinner immediately, so they see something, and start request at the same time.